# reCaptcha with password_reset() in Django

Tags: python, django

urls.py:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'html_email_template_name': 'email_password.html'}, 'password_reset'),
```

I have read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) and looked the code of [password_reset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/).

I need to use reCaptcha when user want to reset password - in **password_reset()** in need to check `request.POST['g-recaptcha-response']` and make request to Google (requests works).

But I don't want write my code in Django source or use packages like [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha).

How can I rewrite **password_reset()** or do something else to resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to create your own view that calls the password reset view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset

def my_password_reset(request):
    # check captcha here
    return password_reset()
```

One of the parameters the password_reset method receives is "password_reset_form", the class of the form you want to use to Reset the password. I would recommend, instead of checking the captcha on your custom view, check it within a new custom form that extends from **django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm**

Comment: Thanks, but in form I can't make request to google and check user response